# Excel cell reference to other workbook using previous date for name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-concatenation

I need to reference data in my current worksheet (a daily log) to the previous day log (to show past day data).

I can do this in a fixed format using a direct reference to the other workbook. However I would really like to have it automatically reference cells in the previous day log. Thankfully the file names are formatted nicely "2016 01 January.xlsm" so referencing them using a formula shouldn't be hard.

I know I can build cell value that shows the previous day name using:

```
=text(today()-1, "yyyy dd Mmmm") & ".xlsm"
```

However, when I attempt to use this within the cell that should reference this sheet it seems my concatenation is broken in:

```
='[TEXT(TODAY()-1, "yyyy dd Mmmm") & ".xlsm"]Readings'!$J$14
```

I could easily debug the concatenation in Matlab, but sadly I'm not in that environment and I don't seem to understand how Excel works as well as I should.

Thanks in advance!
Ben

Comment: See the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to prepend your formula with the INDIRECT command. INDIRECT tells excel that you are not explicitly referring to a particular location, but that you want to dynamically calculate a location, and then refer to that calculated spot. Assuming your file names are correct, this should be as easy as:

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(TODAY()-1, "'\[yyyy dd mmmm") & ".xlsm]Readings'!J14")
```

To test out that it creates the file names correctly, consider putting the concatenation formula in a different cell, and then referring to that cell with INDIRECT. This will confirm for you that you aren't mispelling something etc.

*Edited as highlighted by Jeeped, to now properly calculate the file name instead of hardcoding as an explicit string of text.

Comment: There is more wrong than just the lack of INDIRECT. `=INDIRECT(TEXT(TODAY()-1, "'\[yyyy dd mmmm") & ".xlsm]Readings'!J14")`

Comment: Great! I'd never used INDIRECT, I'll add it to my toolbox though! Thanks again.

Comment: I need a bit more help in getting this to run correctly it seems. I need to add a few directory calls to the beginning of the file name. I believe that I have the proper ' and " marks but I get a #REF! error using this code. I'm using cell C2 to hold the date as it will be read within the workbook I'm building as the current day date. Thus far I have:      =INDIRECT("'\\Network\Directory\Tree\" & TEXT(C2,"yyyy") & " Operations Shift Log\" & TEXT(C2,"yyyy mm Mmmm") & "\" & TEXT(C2-1, "\[yyyy dd mmmm") & ".xlsm]Readings'!$J$14")    which is broken.